# Recurring event

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have been reading lots of recurring topics but still zero ideas on how to implement this logic to my calendar application. I have this table:

```
id | title | start               | end                 | recurring
 1 | test1 | 2011-07-25 08:30:00 | 2011-07-25 10:30:00 |   day
 2 | test2 | 2011-07-26 08:30:00 | 2011-07-26 10:30:00 |   week
 3 | test3 | 2011-07-26 08:30:00 | 2011-07-26 10:30:00 |   month
 4 | test4 | 2011-07-26 08:30:00 | 2011-07-26 10:30:00 |   year
```

When a user view the calendar, I have the parameters send to a url to fetch the data from the database. For example:

Month view:
http://www.domain.com?start=2011-07-01&end=2011-07-31

Week view:
http://www.domain.com?start=2011-07-25&end=2011-07-29

What I have is this so far:

```
SELECT * CASE recurring WHEN "day" THEN IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),"%j") = DATE_FORMAT(e.start,"%j"),1,0) WHEN "week" THEN IF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),"%w") = DATE_FORMAT(e.start,"%w"),1,0) END FROM event;
```

It can retrieve only once...but if I view the calendar for next week 2011-08-01 to 2011-08-05, it will not work.

My question is, how do I retrieve the recurring events based on the url parameters? Any help and advise is greatly appreciated.

PS: I did stumble across this thread: [PHP 5.3 DateTime for recurring events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751380/php-5-3-datetime-for-recurring-events) and it seems close to what I needed but just that I can't figure out in my case how to implement it dynamically with my start and end date time.

Comment: Might be a good idea to show us any code you're currently using to fetch data from your database.

Comment: What does the end date mean? That after that, the recurring date is not recurring anymore? How do you know when a recurring event is not recurring anymore? I don't think your current design can handle recurrence in events appropriately.

Comment: I would edit your question to include that code so others see it straight away.

Comment: @cularis: The end date is just simply the end date. An event can happen 1pm-3pm daily, weekly, or monthly. There is no field to indicate when the recurring will end. If a user view the calendar for the year of 3100, it will still display the event nonetheless. I believe this is normal for all calendars recurring logic.

Comment: Sorry tom, just updated my first post.

Comment: *(tip)* [Martin Fowler: Recurring Events for Calendars (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have read that from Martin fowler before but to be honest, if I can understand that, I can be sure I'll be Martin Fowler number 2...lol.

Answer (score 0):

this is for week and if u change week to monthly etc.. it will work

$sql = "Select form tablename where start > '".$_GET['start']."' and end = '".$_GET['end']."' where recurring = 'week'"

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood my question. Your sql statement only retrieve once for the given event date. What I want is to retrieve an event "weekly" if the recurring is set to "week". But thanks nonetheless.